Why can't I store data into localStorage in Javascript?
I am a beginner in web development, and I am working on a simple bookshelf app. I want to store the book data in localStorage using JavaScript, so the data persists even when the page is refreshed.
However, I am facing the following problem: Whenever I try to add a new book using the form in my app, the book should be saved in localStorage, and the data should be displayed on the page, even after a page reload. However, after submitting the form, the data does not appear in localStorage.
I’ve written a script that attempts to retrieve and save data to localStorage, but it seems like the data isn’t being saved properly.
Here is my code:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Bookshelf App</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Bookshelf App</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section>
      <h2>Tambah Buku Baru</h2>
      <form id="bookForm" data-testid="bookForm">
        <div>
          <label for="bookFormTitle">Judul</label>
          <input id="bookFormTitle" type="text" required data-testid="bookFormTitleInput" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="bookFormAuthor">Penulis</label>
          <input id="bookFormAuthor" type="text" required data-testid="bookFormAuthorInput" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="bookFormYear">Tahun</label>
          <input id="bookFormYear" type="number" required data-testid="bookFormYearInput" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="bookFormIsComplete">Selesai dibaca</label>
          <input id="bookFormIsComplete" type="checkbox" data-testid="bookFormIsCompleteCheckbox" />
        </div>
        <button id="bookFormSubmit" type="submit" data-testid="bookFormSubmitButton">
          Masukkan Buku ke rak <span>Belum selesai dibaca</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h2>Cari Buku</h2>
      <form id="searchBook" data-testid="searchBookForm">
        <label for="searchBookTitle">Judul</label>
        <input id="searchBookTitle" type="text" data-testid="searchBookFormTitleInput" />
        <button id="searchSubmit" type="submit" data-testid="searchBookFormSubmitButton">
          Cari
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h2>Belum selesai dibaca</h2>

      <div id="incompleteBookList" data-testid="incompleteBookList">
       
        <div data-bookid="123123123" data-testid="bookItem">
          <h3 data-testid="bookItemTitle">Judul Buku 1</h3>
          <p data-testid="bookItemAuthor">Penulis: Penulis Buku 1</p>
          <p data-testid="bookItemYear">Tahun: 2030</p>
          <div>
            <button data-testid="bookItemIsCompleteButton">Selesai dibaca</button>
            <button data-testid="bookItemDeleteButton">Hapus Buku</button>
            <button data-testid="bookItemEditButton">Edit Buku</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h2>Selesai dibaca</h2>

      <div id="completeBookList" data-testid="completeBookList">
        
        <div data-bookid="456456456" data-testid="bookItem">
          <h3 data-testid="bookItemTitle">Judul Buku 2</h3>
          <p data-testid="bookItemAuthor">Penulis: Penulis Buku 2</p>
          <p data-testid="bookItemYear">Tahun: 2030</p>
          <div>
            <button data-testid="bookItemIsCompleteButton">Selesai dibaca</button>
            <button data-testid="bookItemDeleteButton">Hapus Buku</button>
            <button data-testid="bookItemEditButton">Edit Buku</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>


main.js
const incompleteBookList = document.getElementById('incompleteBookList');
const completeBookList = document.getElementById('completeBookList');
const bookForm = document.getElementById('bookForm');
const bookFormTitleInput = document.getElementById('bookFormTitle');
const bookFormAuthorInput = document.getElementById('bookFormAuthor');
const bookFormYearInput = document.getElementById('bookFormYear');
const bookFormIsCompleteCheckbox = document.getElementById('bookFormIsComplete');
const bookFormSubmitButton = document.getElementById('bookFormSubmit');

// Retrieve data from localStorage
let books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || [];

// Function to save book data to localStorage
function saveBooks() {
  localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
}

// Function to generate a unique ID using a timestamp
function generateId() {
  return new Date().getTime().toString();
}

// Function to create a book object
function createBookObject(id, title, author, year, isComplete) {
  return { id, title, author, year, isComplete };
}

// Function to create a book element in HTML
function createBookElement(book) {
  const { id, title, author, year, isComplete } = book;
  const bookElement = document.createElement('div');
  bookElement.setAttribute('data-bookid', id);
  bookElement.setAttribute('data-testid', 'bookItem');

  bookElement.innerHTML = `
    <h3 data-testid="bookItemTitle">${title}</h3>
    <p data-testid="bookItemAuthor">Author: ${author}</p>
    <p data-testid="bookItemYear">Year: ${year}</p>
    <div>
      <button data-testid="bookItemIsCompleteButton">${isComplete ? 'Not yet read' : 'Read'}</button>
      <button data-testid="bookItemDeleteButton">Delete Book</button>
      <button data-testid="bookItemEditButton">Edit Book</button>
    </div>
  `;

  const isCompleteButton = bookElement.querySelector('[data-testid="bookItemIsCompleteButton"]');
  const deleteButton = bookElement.querySelector('[data-testid="bookItemDeleteButton"]');
  const editButton = bookElement.querySelector('[data-testid="bookItemEditButton"]');

  // Event to move the book between shelves
  isCompleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggleBookStatus(id);
  });

  // Event to delete a book
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteBook(id);
  });

  // Event to edit a book
  editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    editBook(id);
  });

  return bookElement;
}

// Function to display books on the appropriate shelf
function renderBooks() {
  books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || [];
  console.log("Books to render:", books);

  incompleteBookList.innerHTML = '';
  completeBookList.innerHTML = '';

  books.forEach(book => {
    const bookElement = createBookElement(book);
    if (book.isComplete) {
      completeBookList.appendChild(bookElement);
    } else {
      incompleteBookList.appendChild(bookElement);
    }
  });
}

// Function to add a new book
function addBook(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const title = bookFormTitleInput.value;
  const author = bookFormAuthorInput.value;
  const year = parseInt(bookFormYearInput.value);
  const isComplete = bookFormIsCompleteCheckbox.checked;

  const newBook = createBookObject(generateId(), title, author, year, isComplete);
  books.push(newBook);
  saveBooks();
  renderBooks();
  bookForm.reset();
}

// Function to move a book between shelves
function toggleBookStatus(bookId) {
  const book = books.find(book => book.id === bookId);
  if (book) {
    book.isComplete = !book.isComplete;
    saveBooks();
    renderBooks();
  }
}

// Function to delete a book
function deleteBook(bookId) {
  books = books.filter(book => book.id !== bookId);
  saveBooks();
  renderBooks();
}

// Function to edit a book
function editBook(bookId) {
  const book = books.find(book => book.id === bookId);
  if (book) {
    bookFormTitleInput.value = book.title;
    bookFormAuthorInput.value = book.author;
    bookFormYearInput.value = book.year;
    bookFormIsCompleteCheckbox.checked = book.isComplete;

    deleteBook(bookId);
  }
}

// Function to search for books by title
function searchBooks(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const searchTitle = document.getElementById('searchBookTitle').value.toLowerCase();
  incompleteBookList.innerHTML = '';
  completeBookList.innerHTML = '';

  // Filter books that have titles matching the search query
  const filteredBooks = books.filter(book => book.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle));

  // Render only books that match the search results
  filteredBooks.forEach(book => {
    const bookElement = createBookElement(book);
    if (book.isComplete) {
      completeBookList.appendChild(bookElement);
    } else {
      incompleteBookList.appendChild(bookElement);
    }
  });
}

// Event listener for the book search form
const searchBookForm = document.getElementById('searchBook');
searchBookForm.addEventListener('submit', searchBooks);

// Event listener for the reset search button
const resetSearchButton = document.getElementById('resetSearch');
resetSearchButton.addEventListener('click', renderBooks);

// Event listener to add a new book
bookForm.addEventListener('submit', addBook);

// Display books when the page is first loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', renderBooks);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || []; // Ensure data is retrieved from Local Storage
  renderBooks();
});



The error in the console:
main.js:159 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at main.js:159:19


do you see any errors in the browser developer tools console

yes, the error says : "main.js:159 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at main.js:159:19"

And that error tells you....? (hint: always check whether your query selectors found something before you do something else). And note that the error has nothing to do with what you asked about: you had an error, and instead of looking that error up, you made all kinds of assumptions about what wasn't working, so part of the lesson here is to first find out what's wrong, without making assumptions.

Make sure that getElementById() and querySelector() are called after the DOMContentLoaded event is fired and most of your problems should be solved.
